# DB2 concat two longvarchar columns into new CLOB column

Tags: db2, concatenation, clob

I'm using DB2 9.x and I need to merge two LONG VARCHAR colums 'ETXA' and 'ETXB' (both columns filled with up to 32700 characters) into a new CLOB(150K) column 'ETXALL'.

I tried 
  UPDATE etxdata SET ETXALL = CONCAT( ETXA, ETXB );
and got the error 
SQL0137N The length resulting from "CONCAT" is greater than "0000032700 ". SQLSTATE=54006

I couldn't find a solution to this in the net.
Any idea how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it Db2 for Z/OS, or  Linux/Unix/Windows,  or i-Series ?

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you are using DB2 for LUW) the error message tells you the answer https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0137n

> Character string results are limited to 32,700 bytes unless one of the operands is a CLOB and then the limit is 2 gigabytes.

so try casting your one (or both) of your columns to a `CLOB` before you `CONCAT` them

```
SET ETXALL = CONCAT( CLOB(ETXA), ETXB );
```